# How to add values in multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have a multidimentional array which stores values and I want to add the values of each element in the array and return an array of the total values.

I've created the following function which works, but it seems very bloated for it's purposes. Is there a simpler and cleaner way of doing the following?

```
function get_totals($metric_array){
    $totals['value1']=0;
    $totals['value2']=0;
    $totals['value3']=0;
    $totals['value4']=0;
    $totals['value5']=0;
    $totals['value6']=0;
    $totals['value7']=0;
    $totals['value8']=0;

    foreach ($metric_array as $metric){
        $totals['value1']=$totals['value1']+$metric['value1'];
        $totals['value2']=$totals['value2']+$metric['value2'];
        $totals['value3']=$totals['value3']+$metric['value3'];
        $totals['value4']=$totals['value4']+$metric['value4'];
        $totals['value5']=$totals['value5']+$metric['value5'];
        $totals['value6']=$totals['value6']+$metric['value6'];
        $totals['value7']=$totals['value7']+$metric['value7'];
        $totals['value8']=$totals['value8']+$metric['value8'];  
    }
    return $totals;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct the key `value1`, and make a for loop from 1 to 8. That'll save some code:

```
function get_totals($metric_array){
  for ($i = 1; $ <= 8; $i++) {
    $key = 'value' . $i;
    $totals[$key] = 0;
    foreach ($metric_array as $metric){
      $totals[$key] += $metric[$key];
    }
  }
  return $totals;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see You are trying to return sum of columns.Your function can be optimized like this.

```
    function get_totals($metric_array){
        $totals = array();
        foreach ($metric_array as $metric){
            foreach ($metric as $key => $val){
                $totals[$key] += $val;
            }  
        }
        return $totals;
    }
```